# "Time Limit Exceeded" error for python file

Tags: python-3.x

I have a question about how to improve my simple Python file so that it does not exceed the time limit. My code should run in less than 2 seconds, but it takes a long time. I will be glad to know any advice about it. Code receives (n) as an integer from the user, then in n lines, I have to do the tasks. If the input is "Add" I have to add the given number and then arrange them from smallest to largest. If the input is "Ask", I have to return the asked index of added numbers.

This is
[an example for inputs and outputs.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YvdZp.png)
I guess the code works well for other examples, but the only problem is time ...

```
n = int(input())

def arrange(x):
    for j in range(len(x)):
        for i in range(len(x) - 1):
            if x[i] > x[i + 1]:
                x[i], x[i + 1] = x[i + 1], x[i]

tasks=[]
for i in range(n):
    tasks.append(list(input().split()))

ref = []
for i in range(n):
    if tasks[i][0] == 'Add':
        ref.append(int(tasks[i][1]))
        arrange(ref)
    elif tasks[i][0] == 'Ask':
        print(ref[int(tasks[i][1]) - 1])
```

For the given example, I get a "Time Limit Exceeded" Error.

Comment: Where is this from? Is it online somewhere, so we can see all the details and test potential solutions there?

Comment: Hello Kelly. Yes, you guessed correct. This is my exercise for an online paid python course that judges the code automatically (with a Time limit: ‌ 2 seconds &
Memory limit: 256 MB). They gave one example to test our code (I edited my question and attached their example) but unfortunately, I'm not able to see what other examples their computers tests. I also solved this question with the .sort() method for now but I will welcome any other advice and solution. Thank you for your follow-up and attention.

Comment: I guess *paid* means (1) we don't have access to it and (2) it's really easy to pass the course :-P. The latter would explain why ShadowRanger's code was fast enough (it's still pretty slow compared to what's possible). Does the exercise not say anything about how large n can be, i.e., how many Adds and Asks there can be? And nothing about the range of numbers to add?

Comment: Yes, It's right ;). If I share the link, the content will display unavailable (It's locked). The course is for beginners :D. It's interesting that .sort() is still slow. The exercise says 'n' is 1 =< n =< 100 000. The maximum number of Add/Ask doesn't pass 5000, but unfortunately, there is no information about the range of numbers to add. My challenge was to solve the exercise with specific methods like what I used in my code, but defining the function was optional. (Kelly, your questions are like a guide so I can ask my problem better next time :) )

Comment: Hmm, so there can be 100,000 Add/Ask, but only 5,000 of each? That doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First-off: Reimplementing `list.sort` will always be slower than just using it directly. If nothing else, getting rid of the `arrange` function and replacing the call to it with `ref.sort()` would improve performance (especially because Python's sorting algorithm is roughly `O(n)` when the input is largely sorted already, so you'll be reducing the work from the `O(n**2)` of your bubble-sorting `arrange` to roughly `O(n)`, not just the `O(n log n)` of an optimized general purpose sort).

If that's not enough, note that `list.sort` is still theoretically `O(n log n)`; if the `list` is getting large enough, that may cost more than it should. If so, take a look at the `bisect` module, to let you do the insertions with `O(log n)` lookup time (plus `O(n)` insertion time, but with very low constant factors) which might improve performance further.

Alternatively, if `Ask` operations are going to be infrequent, you might not sort at all when `Add`ing, and only sort on demand when `Ask` occurs (possibly using a flag to indicate if it's already sorted so you don't call `sort` unnecessarily). That could make a meaningfully difference, especially if the inputs typically don't interleave `Add`s and `Ask`s.

Lastly, in the realm of microoptimizations, you're needlessly wasting time on list copying and indexing you don't need to do, so stop doing it:

```
tasks=[]
for i in range(n):
    tasks.append(input().split())  # Removed list() call; str.split already returns a list

ref = []
for action, value in tasks:  # Don't iterate by index, iterate the raw list and unpack to useful
                             # names; it's meaningfully faster
    if action == 'Add':
        ref.append(int(value))
        ref.sort()
    elif action == 'Ask':
        print(ref[int(value) - 1])
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation and the time that you've spent writing. Your solution solved my problem. For a beginner programmer like me, this information was interesting and helpful.

Answer (score 0):

For me it runs in less than 0,005 seconds. Are you sure that you are measuring the right thing and you don't count in the time of giving the input for example?

```
python3 timer.py
Input:
7
Add 10
Add 2
Ask 1
Ask 2
Add 5
Ask 2
Ask 3
Output:
2
10
5
10
Elapsed time: 0.0033 seconds
```

My code:

```
import time

n = int(input('Input:\n'))

def arrange(x):
    for j in range(len(x)):
        for i in range(len(x) - 1):
            if x[i] > x[i + 1]:
                x[i], x[i + 1] = x[i + 1], x[i]

tasks=[]
for i in range(n):
    tasks.append(list(input().split()))

tic = time.perf_counter()

ref = []
print('Output:')
for i in range(n):
    if tasks[i][0] == 'Add':
        ref.append(int(tasks[i][1]))
        arrange(ref)
    elif tasks[i][0] == 'Ask':
        print(ref[int(tasks[i][1]) - 1])

toc = time.perf_counter()
print(f"Elapsed time: {toc - tic:0.4f} seconds")
```

Comment: Handling input should be included in the time. And it will still be almost as fast.